# Why is homebrew telling me I need to have OS X 10.10 or newer, when I'm running 10.11.6?

Tags: macos, homebrew, osx-el-capitan

While trying to install `android-platform-tools` using `homebrew` on OS X 10.11.6, I encountered the following error (complete paste below):

```
$ brew cask install android-platform-tools
==> Satisfying dependencies
==> Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.1-
######################################################################## 100.0% /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/utils/quarantine.swift:29:30: error: 'quarantinePropertiesKey' is only available on OS X 10.10 or newer
      forKey: URLResourceKey.quarantinePropertiesKey
                             ^ /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/utils/quarantine.swift:29:30: note: add 'if #available' version check
      forKey: URLResourceKey.quarantinePropertiesKey
                             ^ Error: Failed to quarantine /Users/User/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/e3de3bef9f7f114325f5d2be854f297cc85e6e17a490c9f267b1c838ee225340--platform-tools_r28.0.1-darwin.zip. Here's the reason: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/utils/quarantine.swift:29:30: error: 'quarantinePropertiesKey' is only available on OS X 10.10 or newer
      forKey: URLResourceKey.quarantinePropertiesKey
                             ^ /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/utils/quarantine.swift:29:30: note: add 'if #available' version check
      forKey: URLResourceKey.quarantinePropertiesKey
                             ^
```

This doesn't make sense to me, since this system is running OS X 10.11.x.

Do I need to completely uninstall and reinstall homebrew? I'd rather not, if possible, since I have a few things installed via homebrew currently.

I did run `brew update` immediately before this, so homebrew should be up to date.

Answer (score 4):

## This is due to a current bug in Homebrew, and a fix has been merged

Per issue [#4809](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/4809):

> Hi, PR #4656 appears to break brew cask install on 10.11. I get an error on 10.11, but not on 10.12. As a workaround, re-running with the --no-quarantine flag is successful. I'm not sure why this swift feature isn't available, my OS is up to date.
>
> (snip)
>
> ```
> /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/utils/quarantine.swift:29:30: error: 'quarantinePropertiesKey' is only available on OS X 10.10 or newer
>       forKey: URLResourceKey.quarantinePropertiesKey
> ```
>
> (etc)

*(snip and etc mine)*

This is the same issue you are facing.

There is a PR ([#4796](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/4796)) that addresses this, which has been merged into master as of a day ago (2018-09-06):

> The Gatekeeper API I've written relies on an up-to-date CLT (or Xcode) install, and xattr's -r flag for native recursion. There are cases where Swift is too old or is set to a deployment target earlier than MacOS 10.10, and thus cannot use the URLResourceKey.quarantinePropertiesKey constant. And in the current Mojave beta, xattr does not have Apple's -r extension for doing native filesystem traversal.
>
> This pull request inserts an additional check in the Swift script, the Quarantine.available? function and brew cask doctor, and changes propagate to use xargs for recursion.

The latest release of `brew` at time of writing is [1.7.3](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tree/1.7.3), released on September 3rd.

**Note**: I just ran a `brew update` and it tells me I am running `1.7.3` running at commit `5d894`, which was committed today (2018-09-07) and is the latest version of [homebrew-core](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core) at time of writing.

### Semi-workaround

If you haven't already downloaded a file, you could try with `no-quarantine`, ie

```
$ brew cask install --no-quarantine android-platform-tools
```

however since you already have those files they should already be quarantined, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the issue/PR find. Interestingly, I was able to workaround using `--no-quarantine`, even though I had already tried the installation unsuccessfully. (Very odd.) 
`brew -v` shows I'm on the same version and commit as you - I wonder why the issue manifested itself...(?)

Comment: Hmm, bit of a puzzler! Not sure why it would manifest itself but at least you were able to work around :)

Comment: Okay, I thought that this would be solved after an update of homebrew, but it isn't. I'm currently on 1.7.3, commit ce9cf9, and I received the exact same error when I tried `brew cask install java`. Is this pull/update supposed to fix the error, or do I need to continue using the `--no-quarantine` flag?